# Filter by property placeholder

Tags: esb, mule

i am trying to let an external properties file decide weather or not a certain flow (and it's inbound endpoint) should be active or not.

Currently, i am trying to achieve this for a flow with a quartz event generator  - and i want to use a custom expression evaluator to stop the flow if it should be active (As defined from the properties file) , but i get an xml error while doing this:
Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:  cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'custom-evaluator' is not allowed to appear in element 'expression-filter'. (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException).

and this is the relevant code: (i am running this on Eclipse with Mule IDE)
`<expression-filter evaluator="custom" custom-evaluator="IsActiveEvaulator" expression="${chFlow.isActive}"/>`

Several issues about this
1) Why is this error happening? i copied the line straight off the website's tutorial.
2) is there a default expression evaulator that could filter based on property placeholder?
3) How would i go about this type of filter with a flow that didnt start with a quartz event generator. meaning, how would i stop a certain flow(and its endpoints) from working depending on a placeholder property.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're being bitten by [a bug](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5863) :(

2) I suggest you create a control bean (say a.b.c.DynamicFlowController), configure it with Spring to inject the placeholder value in it, expose the placeholder value as "isWhateverFlowActive". Then create a custom [intercepting message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.2.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/processor/InterceptingMessageProcessor.html) and place it in your flow after the inbound endpoint as a "custom-message-processor". Inject your control bean in this message processor and use the relevant value to decide if the event must be processed or abandoned.

3) An intercepting message processor will do that for you. If you also expose your control bean over JMX you'll be able to control its initial state from a properties file and then change its state at runtime.

Comment: How would i use the registry evaulator? couldent see anything about it online. I created and injected the bean.

Comment: Also, i dont see how i could use this method in order to configure weather a certain flow works. Meaning i want to be able to use the properties filed in order to determine weather a certain endpoint is created or not.

Comment: I have reviewed my answer to propose an alternative based on Mule's intercepting message processor support. Also I didn't get from your original question you wanted to create endpoints or not. I thought you wanted to drop messages in a flow based on some control logic. If you want to dynamically create endpoints/flows, look at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-dsl

Comment: I knew i'd ask the same question again. but how would i go about exposing the control bean to the JXM?

Comment: I've looked through the mule-dsl guide and whilei see a dynamic creation of a flow what i"m really looking for is some sort of way to invoke a global flow.  is that really impossible in mule??

Comment: You can expose your bean over JMX using the Spring facilities for that: keep in mind that a Mule config is a Spring one :) You can create global flows, ie flows without any endpoint on them and call them (this is done in XML through flow-ref). By code, you would either lookup or inject the global flow and call process on it.